# Parsing simple groups of checkboxes in Go

Tags: forms, text, go, dry, idioms

I'm parsing a form in Go and I frequently find groups of checkboxes which need to be processed into text like so:

```
[ ] Foo
[x] Bar
[ ] Baz
[x] Bat
```

where the output should be a comma-separated list "BarText, BatText" corresponding to the checked items, or "None" if none of the items are checked. What is a good way to handle this situation? Repeating the logic each time seems like a bad idea.

In the spirit of YAGNI there's no need to handle possible future changes like translations into other languages (actually this example is highly unlikely to be useful in the present context).

Efficiency is unimportant for this application.

Edit: code looks like this ([source](http://pastebin.com/c21VFWbs)):

```
func handleCheckboxesForm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    b := func(name string) string { // helper function for boolean values in the form
        return r.FormValue(name) == "on"
    }

    text := "Header stuff here"

    mytext := ""
    if b("nfpa-alk") {
        mytext += ", alkaline"
    }
    if b("nfpa-acid") {
        mytext += ", acid"
    }
    if b("nfpa-w") {
        mytext += ", reacts violently with water"
    }
    if b("nfpa-alk") || b("nfpa-acid") || b("nfpa-w") {
        text += mytext[2:] + "\n"
    } else {
        text += "none\n"
    }

    // lots of other checkbox groups here

    // do stuff with text
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you do it now? HTML form code + Go handler?

Comment: @icza: Nothing fancy, I just defined a local function which returns `r.FormValue(name) == "on"` for a given `name` (where `r` is the current `http.Request`) then use it to concatenate the appropriate strings. I then call the functions a second time to see if I need to concatenate "None". Just the straightforward, boring algorithm.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but since you have a working code which you want to improve, I still find it important to see what to improve.

Comment: @icza: http://pastebin.com/c21VFWbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many repeating code in yours which can be optimized out.

Your code must contain at least the following "fragments":

1. The mappings from entry name to entry text, which can be stored in a map, e.g.

   ```
   var mappings = map[string]string {
       "Foo": "Foo text",
       "Bar": "Bar text",
       "Baz": "Baz text",
       "Bat": "Bat text",
       // ... other mappings
   }
   ```
2. And the list of keys belonging to a group, which can be stored in a slice, e.g.

   ```
   var group1 = []string{"Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Bat"}
   ```

Once you defined these, you can have a helper method which handles a group:

```
func handleGroup(r *http.Request, group []string) (res string) {
    for _, v := range group {
        if r.FormValue(v) == "on" {
            res := ", " + mappings[v]
        }
    }
    if res == "" {
        return "none\n"
    }
    return res[2:] + "\n"
}
```

That's all. After this your handler can be this simple:

```
func checkboxHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Handle group1:
    res1 := handleGroup(r, group1)

    // Handle group2:
    res2 := handleGroup(r, group2)
}
```

**Notes:**

It wasn't your requirement, but this solution handles translations very easily: each translation can have its own `mappings` map, and that's all. Nothing else needs to be changed.

Performance also wasn't your concern, but appending strings isn't very efficient this way. If performance is at least a little concern, you can improve it without adding complexity by utilizing [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer):

```
func handleGroup(r *http.Request, group []string) string {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    for _, v := range group {
        if r.FormValue(v) == "on" {
            buf.WriteString(", ")
            buf.WriteString(mappings[v])
        }
    }
    if buf.Len() == 0 {
        return "none\n"
    }
    buf.WriteString("\n")
    return string(buf.Bytes()[2:])
}
```

Comment: Thank you. :) I'm still getting used to Go and I didn't want to be writing repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

This will store the form values into an array.
Then, it will iterate the array into a string with appending "," at the end of each name. 
Then, it will put very last ", " (2 bytes) if it's longer than 2, otherwise, print "None"

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseMultipartForm(0)
    arr := []string{}
    if r.FormValue("Foo") {
        arr = append(arr, "Foo")
    }
    if r.FormValue("Bar") {
        arr = append(arr, "Bar")
    }
    if r.FormValue("Baz") {
        arr = append(arr, "Baz")
    }
    if r.FormValue("Bat") {
        arr = append(arr, "Bat")
    }
    out := ""
    for _, title := range arr {
        out += title +", "
    }
    if len(out) > 2 {
        out := out[0: len(out)-2]   
    } else {
        out = "None"
    }

    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

If you want to iterate,

```
for k, vs:= range r.Form {   
  for _, v:= range vs{
     fmt.Println(k, v)
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to add it to array, you can just adding text for each "if" syntax.

Comment: This is similar to what I'm doing now. My question is how should I handle cases where I have many collections of checkboxes -- should I repeat this code, or is there some way to modularize it?